# Static library -L not found

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, static-libraries

I am importing some static libraries to my project. It works fine but there are some compiler warnings as "...  following -L not found". This is seen in every static library I import. How to resolve those error?

Thank You

Comment: -L option is for including directories in the search path (not static libraries), so why do you say a static library is not found?

Comment: Yes I get that waring. Not sure why it is.

Comment: Tried -l (lowercase) instead of -L?

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue with a codebase that didn't originate on my machine.  I stuck it in a folder with a space in its name, which seemed to confuse the header search paths.  Closing the project, taking the space out of the folder name and restarting fixed the linker.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have checked "Recursive" option for a folder with no subfolder. If so uncheck it. I too have faced this problem already

Comment: Still having the same problem even though I add it as reference not as recursive groups